# GIT newbie confused at commit message (how to move on without screwing things up)

Tags: git, vim

Not really a programmer, just trying to get VisualEditor extension installed on a shared host MediaWiki installation. It requires JSON and the recommended method is to go through Heroku for that. Using the instructions found at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/VisualEditor/Installation_on_a_shared_host

Those instructions are out of date (but the best I could find) as you now edit the config.yaml file and NOT the localsettings.js. Anyway, I am up to step 21 (out of 29). I have no idea what editor I am seeing and the commands don't work for getting out of it.

A screenshot of what I'm seeing can be viewed here:

[image: http://www.antiqueauto.org/assets/GIT-window.png]
<sub>(source: [antiqueauto.org](http://www.antiqueauto.org/assets/GIT-window.png))</sub>

I last worked on this before Labor Day, but left my computer running and the cmd.exe window open, so hoping to just pick up where I left off. But can't get out of this window (and really have no clue how GIT/Heroku/JSON actually work... just trying to follow the steenkin' instructions.

Answer (score 2):

looks like you're in the VIM editor.. type :quit  (with the colon) and if that doesn't work, hit esc to get into "command" mode and try again. :q or :quit should work for you.

Once out of it, try

```
$ vimtutor
```

it's a good way to get acquainted with VIM.

Comment: And if you don't like `vim`, read the git manual and learn how to configure a different editor that will be used for things like commit messages, etc.

Comment: The most sure-fire way to get out is Escape Escape `:quit!`, especially since the OP clearly has changes; there are special nested modes, but I've never needed to hit Escape more than twice, IIRC.

Comment: Thanks to all for the answers/input. We got the job done and VisualEditor is working with the wiki on a shared host, thanks to JSON on Heroku.